# Python argument missed if I pass $ inside string as input parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to pass some shell cmd into one of my python script so that I can run them toward hosts. However, when I pass them into the line, the $ is omitted for some reason. How can I avoid this?

I use parser and setup like this:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='check size', add_help=True)
parser.add_argument('-c', "--cmd", dest="cmd",type=str, help="Command to run Ex: df -h /boot/|grep -i boot|awk '{print \$4}' 2>/dev/null ")
```

Ex:
This is working with a backslash

```
python3.4 disk_file_check.py -e env -op chksize -c "df -h /boot/|grep -i boot|awk {'print \$4'} 2>/dev/null"
```

since anybody can use this script and all they should pass is just the command they want to use. but I want it works like this:

```
python3.4 disk_file_check.py -e env -op chksize -c "df -h /boot/|grep -i boot|awk {'print $4'} 2>/dev/null"
```

But when I do this, The string is turned into:

```
df -h /boot/|grep -i boot|awk '{print }' 2>/dev/null
```

As you can see $ is cutting out and give me wrong result...

Any possible setting in argparse can do it?  or I should try diff way? Thanks

Comment: I am using python3 on this one.... but do not think any differ in python2/3

Comment: This is not a python problem, but one of the shell, e.g. `bash`.

Comment: The `$4` is inside double quotes, so the shell expands it. The caller has to escape the `$` or use single quotes around the argument to `-c`.

Comment: The issue arises ini the shell, there's nothing Python can do about it.

Comment: The problem is that you have a variable `$4` that is enclosed in double quotes.  (It's _also_ nested in single quotes, but that doesn't matter.)  The shell will ALWAYS try to expand that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I think I will not pass this through command line since shell exapnd it. Thanks for pointing that out.